# Editing system files with PHPStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Just moved over to PHPStorm from Sublime Text 2, & am having trouble editing system files (e.g. /etc/hosts).  In ST2 it would prompt for my admin account username & password when I attempted to save the file.  PS does not do that.  Just reports 'Permission denied'.

Is there a way of editing these file usign PHPStorm without using being logged in with admin account?

Comment: Sublime is a text editor. PHPStorm is an integrated development environment. You wouldn't use chef's knives to spread peanut butter on bread.

Comment: *"Is there a way of editing these file usign PHPStorm without using being logged in with admin account?"* -- launch PhpStorm with admin rights from the start (`Run As Administrator`)? In any case -- this software was not designed to work the way you are trying to use it (as general text editor, for example).

Comment: Why on earth would you want to edit the `hosts` file with PHPStorm?

Comment: I'm not asking about the suitability of the program for editing the files.  PHPStorm has text editing fiunctionality.  I'm trying to edit text files.
In case you missed the question, HOW do I edit them, or for that matter, how might I edit PHP files that I'm not the owner of?!
Saying that, thanks to @LazyOne for a constructive answer.  Care to add that as an answer so I can acknowledge it properly.  Ta.

Comment: Small note: I have not used ST2 myself, but from your description ST2's behaviour is some advanced and intelligent stuff -- not even Windows' own Notepad .. or popular Notepad++ does this. As far as I remember (sorry, cannot guarantee 100% accuracy) even VS2008/2010 does not do this. So I assume it's safe to say that current behaviour is pretty standard.

Comment: @LazyOne, ah perhaps I should have mentioned, I'm on a Mac.